# Automapper map nested collection

Tags: automapper

I'm new to Automapper, and struggling to get a custom mapping working. I'm using 1.1 so that it works with .net 3.5.

Essentially, I want to create a list for my DTO which is built using one subclass contained within the list class of the parent model.

Below should better illustrate what I mean:

```cs
public class RedCar
{
public string Name{get;set;}
public List<RedCarPart> RedCarParts(get;set;}
}

public class RedCarPart
{
public string RedCarSerial{get;set;}
public CarPart Carpart {get;set;}
}

public class CarPart
{
public int PartID {get;set;}
public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class CarDTO
{
public string name{get;set;}
public List<CarPartDTO> carparts{get;set;}
}

public class CarPartDTO
{
public int PartID {get;set;}
public string description {get;set;}
}
```

I don't need the extra information provided within RedCarPart, and so I just need a list of CarParts.

I know I can just replicate RedCarPartDTO, and ignore the fields I don't need, but rather than pass that down to the client, I feel it would be better to see if I can just map a list of CarParts.

I'm thinking it must be to do with map from, but I'm having trouble with how I'm doing this:

```cs
 Mapper.CreateMap<RedCar, CarDTO>()
            .ForMember(s => s.CarParts, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.RedCarParts));

        Mapper.CreateMap<RedCarPart, CarPartDTO>()
       .ForMember(s => s.PartID, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.CarPart.PartID))
        .ForMember(s => s.Description, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.CarPart.Description));
```

Comment: It should work if your `CarPartDTO` only contains a property `CarPart`.

Comment: Sorry @Gert, I'm don't think I added enough info in the question (I've now added 2 extra classes).  I want to make a CarPartDTO list from the RedCarPart list, but have this consisting only of the CarPart properties. Essentially, this is the only property I am interested in from RedCarPart.

Comment: OK, so what exactly is the "trouble"? Is it the first mapping? Its `.ForMember` looks unnecessary to me.